# StackView FIll Equally not working properly NSTextFields

Tags: swift, nstextfield, stackview

I have an NSStackView which holds multiple NSTextFields. I put StackView distribution to

- Fill Equally

But when one of the textFields has content higher than actual width. It goes wrong:
[image]

The stackView works perfectly when the content size is less than it's width.
[image]

Tried many ways to achieve by changing Content Hugging Priority of each textfield, also tried with hugging priority of stackView. But didn't work though. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: Have you given any width constraints to textfields ?

Comment: No. I didn't give any width constraints to textfields

Comment: It looks like something wrong you have done. I can not regenerate the same issue. can you please show some constraints and stack properties.

Comment: Ok. I got it Nisarg. I was using custom TextFieldCell & this was setting it's width. So I removed it. Now it's working as required.